# Stability in coefficients for the rescaled radiative tranport equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, perturbation-theory

One form of the radiative transport equation is as follows:
$$ v\cdot \nabla_x u + \left(\epsilon \sigma_a(x) + \frac{1}{\epsilon}\sigma_s(x)\right) u - \frac{1}{\epsilon}\sigma_a(x)\int_{S^{n-1}} p(v,v')u(x,v')\,dv'= 0$$
Here $u = u(x,v)$, $x\in X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ for some convex domain $X$ with smooth boundary, $v\in S^{n-1}$. The coefficients $\sigma_a$ and $\sigma_s$ are the absorbing and scattering coefficients respectively, which we assume to be in $L^\infty$. We also assume $p(v,v') = p(v\cdot v')$ integrates to 1 in the sense that $\int p(v,v')dv' = 1$.

We also have the following boundary condition: define
$$\Gamma_- = \{(x,v)\in \partial X\times S^{n-1}: \nu(x)\cdot v < 0\},$$
where $\nu(x)$ is the outer unit normal. Then we prescribe $u|_{\Gamma_-} = g(x,v)$. It is known that in this case, solutions exist and live in the space
$$W = \{u\in L^1(X\times S^{n-1}): v\cdot \nabla_x u\in L^1(X\times S^{n-1}\}$$

**My question is this:** Let $0<\epsilon\ll 1$ and $v$ solve the same equation, but with the $\epsilon\sigma_a(x)$ coefficient dropped from the integro-differential equation. Then can we say something along the lines of $\|u - v\|_{L^\infty(X\times S^{n-1})} = o(\epsilon)$? Is there some result from perturbation theory that would apply here?